# Como fazer que o scroll "pule" para uma div ou link interno em jQuery (Ou JS puro)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, rolamento

Exemplo: https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ e https://www.casacomseara.com.br/, conforme você usa o scroll do mouse para cima ou para baixo, você vai "saltando" entre os conteúdos ou divs.

É isso que eu procuro em jQuery, ao usar scroll, ir até o conteúdo.

Já tentei pesquisar sobre, o máximo que consegui foi "scrollar de maneira fixa", tipo todo scroll que eu der, o site se mover 100% para cima ou para baixo, é uma solução parecida mas não é o que eu procuro. 
O "trigger" é o scroll, imaginando que eu tenha ao total 5 divs em meu site, e eu esteja na div 3, se eu scrollar para baixo eu iria saltar para a div 4 e se scrollar para cima eu iria saltar para a div 2, estando na div 2 eu poderia ir para a div 1 ou retornar a div 3, dependendo se eu dou scroll para baixo ou para cima. Infelizmente não da para explicar utilizando uma imagem, peço para que visite o site para uma maior compreensão.

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, eu não conseguia encontrar a resposta para a minha dúvida por não saber o termo "scroll hijacking", sabendo disso...não acha que é necessário essa pergunta ter uma resposta dizendo que o que eu busco se chama scroll hijacking ao mesmo tempo em que mereça um voto positivo pois acredito que muitos também desconheçam o termo "scroll hijacking". Então minha pergunta seria útil para isso.

Comment: Eu também desconheço o termo, mas fiz uma pesquisa no buscador do site por "fullPage" e apareceram poucas perguntas, a ultima era a que continha a solução para o problema. PS: não precisa apagar a sua pergunta, duplicata não é "pergunta errada", ela serve como apontamento, ou seja a sua pergunta é util para que as pessoas cheguem a outra pergunta, até mesmo para o google irá ajudar.